# Stuck in "Starting selenium server" when running sample nightwatch test

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, nightwatch.js

Having some issues with nightwatch.js - I have an existing project directory and I'm trying to install it. I have followed an instructional article, but when I try to run the test, it fails to start the selenium server and gets stuck. It would be helpful if someone could tell me what is the issue. I am using Windows 10 and I am trying to run the test in Chrome.

Here is my nightwatch.json config file - I made it from scratch which is why it isn't lengthy:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "lib/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar",
    "start-session" : true,
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "lib/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "chrome" : {
        "desiredCapabilities": {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "javascriptEnabled": true,
          "acceptSslCerts": true
        }



    }
  }
}
}
```

This is the only test that I have in the test folder, and it looks like this:

```
module.exports = {   'Demo test Google' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .windowMaximize()
      .url('http://www.google.com')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
      .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
      .click('button[name=btnG]')
      .pause(1000)
      .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch')
      .end();   } };
```

My steps to reproduce:

1. Open CMD and CD into my project/lib/selenium folder, and run line

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar
    This starts the selenium server without any issues.
 2. Next, in a separate console, I CD into my project root folder and run the command line

```
node nightwatch.js -t tests/sample.js
```

This then says "Starting selenium server..." but doesn't actually open any browser or run any tests. It stays in this state, and I have to close the command console and re-open it if I want to try again.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest adding tags to your test case and trying initialising browser with init() :

```
module.exports = {
    '@tags': ['demo-test'],
    'Trying first demo test': (browser) => {
         browser
             .init()
             .url('http://www.google.com')
             .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
             ...(all the assertions you need)...
          };
```

Besides this you should not need to start selenium server in a separate terminal window - nightwatch is supposed to it by itself. So in the terminal just cd into your projects folder and type nightwatch to start the whole setup running.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it after correctly checking all my paths in nightwatch.json file.
Make sure that you are specifying the correct path to chrome driver and selenium.
I've noticed that you forgot about file extension on chrome driver, try

```
"webdriver.chrome.driver" : "lib/chromedriver.exe",
```